# activeuuid string into hexadecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using activeUUID gem in rails application
I generated uuid with activeuuid as:

```
"83fd59ff-bfd1-4820-a45f-8927db5f87cc"
```

want to convert it like below:

```
 x'83fd59ffbfd14820a45f8927db5f87cc'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself using uuidtools gem :

```
UUIDTools::UUID.parse("83fd59ff-bfd1-4820-a45f-8927db5f87cc")
```

The above code will produce:

```
  x'83fd59ffbfd14820a45f8927db5f87cc'
```